# How do I discover the features of a product that are most valued by customers?

Tags: tools

What tools or frameworks exist to identify which features of a product would add the most value to a customer?

Comment: I was tempted to rewrite this question to make it more targeted and less open-ended, but then realized that what's missing is the OP's specific context. Polling questions are off-topic here, but a specific question that you're facing within a given context would certainly be relevant. Please add more information about what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what parts of it aren't working optimally for you. Then folks will be glad to offer constructive answers to your question.

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad. See the [faq#close] for guidance on how to make your question fit our framework. Also, this is a duplicate of your previous question: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/product-management-analytical-tools-and-frameworks-to-determine-which-product. Instead of writing a new question, follow the guidance in the [faq] to improve this one by making an [edit]. Good luck!

Comment: Reopened to see if the community can help @Robert Voyt

Comment: I don't think this is a useful question as it stands - it needs the changes that @jmort253 recommended to be answered without just being a list of tools that don't speak to OP's context. Voting to close accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Market research, analysis, and surveillance for high performing products and trends, various surveys and focus groups. This comes down to basic research, risk analysis, and product pro forma. Ask the customer what they want. That said, some of the highest performing products were from those trend setting companies that told us what we wanted and needed.